# CSS - Set parent's height to 0 but child div still show

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to make a simple animation to show and hide a component.

```css
#parent {
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">This is some content</div>
</div>
```

When I set parent div height to 0, I expect the child div also not visible, but the child still showing. I want to make it disappear when parent height set to 0.

What is the problem here and what I'm I doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Set overflow:hidden to parent container.

Comment: do you want the child component grow on parent height ?

Comment: @Adeebbasheer : Not really. I just want when parent height is 0, the child should also not visible.

Answer (score 55):

Add overflow hidden property to the parent object. This way overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible (in subject case height is 0 so remaining will also be 0).

```
#parent {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple and works. 
Can I ask some more? This way the child is still consume space of the page, how to make it not consume space?

Comment: can you give a plunker link or a screenshot

Comment: Thank you, with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/v6way9vo/ it works as expected. So maybe the problem I'm facing is related to Angular2 <tag> that not work as I expected. Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: In this Angular 2 Plunker, https://embed.plnkr.co/BxT8SKBq8JwuPP16FDu4/ . I want to toggle hide and show a component, but seem like it not work as expected? Do you know the reason why? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

After add **`overflow: hidden`** whatever is written in a child `DOM`, it will be disappear

```css
#parent {
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    This is some content..
    This is some content..
    This is some content..
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same issue and the other solutions weren't working. My issue was simple. I needed to set padding to 0 in the element that I wanted to collapse and then it disappeared as I wanted it to.